# Vlookup entire row

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vlookup

I want to search an entire row using Vlookup from another sheet in my workbook. Currently I can only fetch the Name using excel. With sample data & searching for 123

```
Sheet 1
     ID    Name     Rates
    ----  ------   -------
     123   Onions    25$
     125   Tomatoes   6$

   Sheet2
       VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!B3:D5,2)
```

gives me 123, Onions. I want 123, Onions, **25$**.

Comment: Did you try `VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!B3:D5,3)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sheet1**

```
 ID    Name     Rates
----  ------   -------
 123   Onions    25$
 125   Tomatoes   6$
```

**Sheet2**

```
 ID
----
 125
```

Then you could use this for cell `B1`:

```
=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!A2:C5;2;0);", ";VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!A2:C5;3;0))
```